# Does Google Cloud Pub / Sub Resend Messages To Background Functions If They Return A Callback Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

The official documentation does mention that Google Cloud Pub / Sub resends messages to subscribers until subscribers acknowledge the message receipt when using official Cloud Pub / Sub Node.js client.

But it does not explicitly mention this for background functions if they return a callback error. Refer https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background.

If it helps - My background function does not use the official Cloud Pub / Sub Node.js client since I get all the required info from the event arguement itself.

Comment: So your subscriber using is using push pubsub, right? Is your code trapping the error and generating an http error response?

Comment: It's a Background Function which can be called as push. I do send an error with the callback.

Answer (score -1):

From documentation: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries

> Cloud Functions guarantees at-least-once execution of a background
>   function for each event emitted by an event source. However, by
>   default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the
>   function will not be invoked again, and the event will be dropped.
>   When you enable retries on a background function, Cloud Functions will
>   retry a failed function invocation until it completes successfully, or
>   the retry window expires.

And described below, you can enable retry on errors:

> In any of the above cases, the function stops executing by default and
>   the event is discarded. If you want to retry the function when an
>   error occurs, you can change the default retry policy by setting the
>   "retry on failure" property. This causes the event to be retried
>   repeatedly for up to multiple days until the function successfully
>   completes.